# Oersted's Law in differential form notation

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms, electromagnetism

I'm preparing to get chewed up on a midterm and I don't yet know how to write Oersted's Law in differential form notation.

The goal is to convert this

$\int_{\partial S} H \cdot dr  = \int_{s} \nabla \times H \cdot da$ ~ I

to differential form.

How does one proceed?

Comment: Note that $$\int_S \nabla \times \vec H\cdot \hat n\,dS=\int_S  \vec J\cdot \hat n\,dS$$What can you deduce now?

Comment: From the definition of $F:=  - E_x dt \wedge dx - E_y dt \wedge dy -  E_z dt \wedge dz + B_x dy \wedge dz + By dz  \wedge dx + B_z dx \wedge dy$  It seems  $d(*F) = J$ so I am guessing something close to the form $\int  d(*F)$ . Still thinking though

Comment: If for all surfaces $S$, $\int_S \vec F\cdot \hat n\, dS=0$, what can one deduce about $\vec F$?

Comment: The net flux through the surfaces is zero.

Comment: By gauss's theorem, it would seem that one either has no sources or sinks  / or one has sources and sinks that cancel each other resulting in zero flux. For a fixed cubic volume the density can only change by spilling fluid out of the cube sides.

Comment: Here the fluid is field lines and density is the charge (source/sinks) I think all this could be flawed thinking of course.

Comment: Be careful here. Does @MarkViola mean all closed surfaces (i.e., $\partial S = \emptyset$) or all surfaces?

Comment: @TedShifrin All surfaces.  Use of any closed surface leads to a tautology of $0=0$.  Note that the law is typically written for non-closed surfaces, even though it trivially applies to closed surfaces.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, I realized, but the OP followed up by applying Gauss's Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, I see your point--alert the OP as to the issue.  ;-)

Comment: Ok, I have now read the comment. I think I follow. Gauss's theorem was pushing it a bit. I had a picture of a box in my head and got carried away.